# codeigniter, form image upload

Tags: php, forms, image, codeigniter, upload

I have a simple form, I've added image upload to it.

But I'm having trouble writing to the database.

Picture is uploaded to folder, all operations except picture are written to database but the form is not successful because the image is not written to the database.

This is my controller:

```
public function send_Basvur_message(){

    $config['upload_path']          = './panel/uploads/basvur_v/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 4096;
    $config['overwrite']            = false;
    $config['encrypt_name']         = false;
    $config['remove_space']         = true;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('avatara');

    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $this->load->model("Basvur_model");

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("name", "Ad", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "E-posta", "trim|required|valid_email");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("subject", "Konu", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("message", "Mesaj", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("avatar", "avatar", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("captcha", "Doğrulama Kodu", "trim|required");

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        // TODO Alert...
        $this->session->set_flashdata('info','Action Completed');
        redirect(base_url("basvuru"));
    } else {

        $insert = $this->Basvur_model->add(
            array(
                "name"          => $this->input->post("name"),
                "email"         => $this->input->post("email"),
                "message"       => $this->input->post("message"),
                "subject"       => $this->input->post("subject"),
                "avatar"        => $this->input->post("avatar"),
                "created_at"    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
            )
        );

        if($this->session->userdata("captcha") == $this->input->post("captcha")){

            $name = $this->input->post("name");
            $email = $this->input->post("email");
            $subject = $this->input->post("subject");
            $message = $this->input->post("message");
            $avatar = $this->input->post("avatar");

            $email_message = "{$name} isimli ziyaretçi. Başvuru Yaptı <br><b>Mesaj : </b> {$message} <br> <b>E-posta : </b> {$email}";

            if(send_email("", "Yeni Aday başvurusu | $subject", $email_message)){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
                redirect(base_url("basvuru"));
                // TODO Alert..
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
                redirect(base_url("basvuru"));
                // TODO Alert..
            }

        } else {
            //başarısıs
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Action Not Completed');
        redirect(base_url("basvuru"));

        }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `$this->input->post("avatar")` for file name. You have to use `$this->upload->data()` for getting the file name after uploading the file using `$this->upload->do_upload('avatara')`. Get the value of `$this->upload->data()` in a variable and send to model.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can get image name using
```

```
$config['file_name'] =$_FILES['avatar']['name'];

$config['upload_path'] = './images/contents/'; /* NB! create this dir! */
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['max_size']  = '0';
$config['max_width']  = '0';
$config['max_height']  = '0';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
{
 $data['msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
 $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_succ',$data['msg']);


}
else
{
  $data = $this->upload->data();
  $uploadedImages['image'] = $data['file_name'];
  $image = $uploadedImages['avatar'];

    here you can update image name in database`enter code here`             

}
```